# Bootstrap 3 - Input group inside page header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to move an input group inside of my page header. When I try to use a row with columns, the HR doesn't run all the way through which bothers me.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="page-header">
         <h3 class="text-primary">EMP <small>My Dashboards</small></h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Results..." id="search" name="search">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eo75juzL/

I am just trying to move the search input group to be right-aligned with the `H3` and keep the line running all the way through.

Comment: You can see in your fiddle that it is right-aligned. So the problem has to be elsewhere.

Comment: @Sebastian - I can also see that the bottom border for the page-header cuts off due to it only spanning `col-8` which is what I am trying to fix. I understand the defining its width is going to contain it but I dont know how else to keep it on the same line without the row/col

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/eo75juzL/5/

Comment: @Sebastian - That should work, will just need to play with the height to get them even but at least the placement is right. Thanks

Comment: `.page-header, .input-group {margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo75juzL/8/).

The horizontal line is part of the `page-header`, so I moved your columns within this div. Normal bootstrap behavior now applies, and your search box is right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

To place your search box inside header You need to add this css.

```
.dash_input {
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```css
.dashboard {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.dash_input {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           </head>
           <body>
           <div class="row">
           <div class="page-header">
      <div class=" dashboard col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 ">
  
      <h3 class="text-primary">EMP <small>My Dashboards</small></h3>
   </div>
      <div class="dash_input col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-right">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Results..." id="search" name="search">
         </div>
      
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
           </body>
           </html>
```

You had some problem with your div mark-up. tried to fix that. take a look at the above snippet. Also I would suggest you to use `class="navbar"`. in that case you would have more flexibility.